# Can I share ipa files OTA without collecting UDIDs through a 99$ publisher account

Tags: ios, distribution, adhoc, ota, udid

I want to know can ipa files be shared through a 99$ publisher account without demanding the UDID of your testers, as in an enterprise account.

Answer (score 1):

No. Each `ipa` file contains `embedded.mobileprovision` file. This files contains information about provisioning profile app was signed and devices on which app can be installed. If UDID not in this file then app can't be installed on this device.

Look at service https://testflightapp.com/ It can help you collect info about devices and publish builds.